# Как сделать XRDP в Ubuntu 14, для всех пользователей?

Tags: ubuntu, xrdp

Настроил XRDP в Ubuntu 14. Для пользователя который создавался при установке ОС, все работает хорошо. А вот если создать нового пользователя, и попробовать через него подключиться, то - серый экран. Подскажите, в чем тут причина может быть? В какую сторону копать?

p.s. я новичок в линуксе, уже много всего перерыл, .xsession с параметрами для созданного пользователя создавал - не дало результатов.
Лог

```html
Сценарий для ibus запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для auto запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для default запущен из run_im.
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: Процесс at-spi2-registryd main завершен, повторный запуск
init: at-spi2-registryd возрождается слишком быстро, остановлен
init: Процесс unity-panel-service main (27894) завершен с кодом 1
init: Процесс indicator-printers main (27970) завершен с кодом 1
init: Процесс unity-settings-daemon main (27883) завершен с кодом 1
init: Процесс hud main (27887) завершен с кодом 1
init: Процесс gnome-session (Unity) main (27891) завершен с кодом 1
init: Процесс indicator-bluetooth main (27953) завершен с помощью сигнала TERM
init: Процесс indicator-power main (27958) завершен с помощью сигнала TERM
init: Процесс indicator-datetime main (27959) завершен с помощью сигнала TERM
init: Процесс indicator-session main (27974) завершен с помощью сигнала TERM
init: Процесс indicator-application main (27989) завершен с помощью сигнала TERM
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
Xsession: X session started for  at Вс. июня 14 11:00:42 MSK 2015
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:narvel being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
Сценарий для ibus запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для auto запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для default запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для ibus запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для auto запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для default запущен из run_im.
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[2640]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Дочерний процесс завершился с кодом 1
gnome-session[2640]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Xsession: X session started for  at Вс. июня 14 11:05:22 MSK 2015
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:narvel being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
Сценарий для ibus запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для auto запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для default запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для ibus запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для auto запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для default запущен из run_im.
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[2847]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Дочерний процесс завершился с кодом 1
gnome-session[2847]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

```html
Xsession: X session started for  at Вс. июня 14 10:57:17 MSK 2015
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:narvel being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
Сценарий для ibus запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для auto запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для default запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для ibus запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для auto запущен из run_im.
Сценарий для default запущен из run_im.
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[26970]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Дочерний процесс завершился с кодом 1
gnome-session[26970]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Comment: судя по логам, вы пытаетесь запустить слишком требовательную к видео-аппаратуре графическую сессию. попробуйте что-то менее накладное. например, по умолчанию *gnome* использует *compiz* в качестве *window manager*-а, и стоит попробовать вместо него, например, *metacity*. для этого надо установить пакет *gnome-session-flashback* и выбрать при логине сессию без *compiz*-а: [screenshot](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-H8thD4cyFJo/U1EoIqhD_eI/AAAAAAAASXI/E-W__jPr1nI/s1600/gnome-flashback-login-screen.png)

Answer (score 1):

приходит в голову разве что членство в группах.

попробуйте внести нового пользователя в те же группы, что и первого (за исключением, конечно, групп *sudo* и «персональной» группы, имя которой совпадает с именем пользователя).

узнать, в какие группы входит пользователь, можно командой

```
$ groups имя_пользователя
```

добавить в группу:

```
$ sudo adduser имя_пользователя имя_группы
```

после добавления пользователя в группу(-ы) эффект наступит не сразу, а лишь после завершения всех процессов, запущенных от имени этого пользователя.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали - не помогло, все так же и осталось. Логи прикрутил